# Execute two AsyncTask in two activities android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

I am making an android app with 3 activities for the moment, that get data from distant server , I used `AsyncTask`, it works perfectly .

**Activity A & Activity B Activity C** :

Activity A executes an AsyncTask  (Task_A) and in onPostExecute, I launch the second Activity_B , that will execute an AsyncTask (Task_B) in onResume., and the second onPostExecute,the third activity will excute .

**In Activty A :**

```
// GetResults1 task1 =new  GetResults1();
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
          task1.execute();
    }

  private class GetResults1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // here my code (it worked finally)
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
         }
```

**In Activty B :**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.i("LOADING", "onResume");
super.onResume();
    GetResults2 task2 =new  GetResults2();
    task2.execute();
}

  private class GetResults2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // here my code (it worked finally)
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
         }
```

**THE PROBLEM Now :**

If I run my app and see the logcat :  the second asynck Task executes before onStop of the  first activity.

```
OnCreate Activity_A
OnStart Activity_A
OnResume Activity_A
Task_1 begin         // action button
onPreExecute Task_1
doInBackground Task_1
onPostExecute Task_1
OnPause Activty_A              |||||||||||

OnCreate Activity_B               ||||||
OnStart Activity_B                 
OnResume Activity_B
Task_2 begin 
onPreExecute Task_2
doInBackground Task_2
onPostExecute Task_2

OnStop Activity_A
```

I want that the second AsynckTask executes when ActivityA executes  onStop method.

Comment: Instead of starting the second `Activity` in the `onPostExecute(...)` method of the first `Activity` start it in the `onStop()` method of the first `Activity`. In the `onPostExecute(...)` method of the first `Activity` simply call `finish()` which makes the first `Activity` self-terminate.

Comment: thnx for reply , but when i do that , the first activity dissapear, and the second asynckTask excute ,and after it indoBackground tha second Activty appear :/